# Delete a Microsoft Planner Plan as Administrator

Tags: microsoft-planner

As an administrator: How can I delete a plan created by another user? I do not see any options as if I delete my own plans. Do I need a specific organizational role?

Answer (score 1):

Problem solved (or: no problem...):
O365 Admin -> Admin Center -> Exchange -> Recipients -> Groups -> edit group.
Adding me as an owner there allows me to delete the Plan in Planner. Affects MS teams also